# locking hive table from spark HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive

We are setting up hive for our Data warehousing need and using spark for processing while hive as storage. Our files are really small (<10KB) but huge in numbers. Requirement is to provide data in near to realtime. So my approach each create a partition on hive to indicate its CURRENT or PAST. Keep publishing data in current but after certain interval aggregate it and move to partition PAST. But when move operation is going on I need to lock table, since it may give inaccurate data.

for hive CLI there is no issue.

```
hive> LOCK TABLE t26013_75 exclusive;
OK
Time taken: 0.106 seconds
```

But when I try same on spark

```
scala> val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
16/04/07 07:14:55 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 0.13.1
hiveContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@723fadfe

scala> hiveContext.sql("LOCK TABLE ma.t26013_75 exclusive")
16/04/07 07:15:00 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: LOCK TABLE ma.t26013_75 exclusive
16/04/07 07:15:00 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
16/04/07 07:15:00 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 0.13.1 using Spark classes.
16/04/07 07:15:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/04/07 07:15:01 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083
16/04/07 07:15:01 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.run from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: LOCK TABLE ma.t26013_75 exclusive
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=parse start=1460027702353 end=1460027702784 duration=431 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO ql.Driver: Semantic Analysis Completed
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze start=1460027702785 end=1460027702832 duration=47 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO ql.Driver: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=compile start=1460027702328 end=1460027702841 duration=513 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.execute from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO ql.Driver: Starting command: LOCK TABLE ma.t26013_75 exclusive
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit start=1460027702325 end=1460027702861 duration=536 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=runTasks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=task.DDL.Stage-0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO lockmgr.DummyTxnManager: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
16/04/07 07:15:02 ERROR exec.DDLTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: lock Table LockManager not specified
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.lockTable(DDLTask.java:2880)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runSqlHive(HiveContext.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveNativeCommand.run(HiveNativeCommand.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:755)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line68.$read.<init>(<console>:46)
    at $line68.$read$.<init>(<console>:50)
    at $line68.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line68.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line68.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line68.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

16/04/07 07:15:02 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. lock Table LockManager not specified
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1460027702841 end=1460027702880 duration=39 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1460027702880 end=1460027702880 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/04/07 07:15:02 ERROR client.ClientWrapper: 
======================
HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. lock Table LockManager not specified

======================
END HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================

org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. lock Table LockManager not specified
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runSqlHive(HiveContext.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveNativeCommand.run(HiveNativeCommand.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:755)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
    at <init>(<console>:46)
    at .<init>(<console>:50)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: what is your Spark and Hive versions?

Comment: hive is 2.0.0 and Spark 1.4.1. Hive is configured with MySQL as metastore

Answer (score 0):

I watched log more carefully and got fixed after add following

```
scala> hiveContext.setConf("hive.support.concurrency","true")
```

I do not know why it asks. I already have hive-site.xml in hive/conf location.

It may be because my hive-site.xml at spark/conf have just following entry

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
</property>
```

Will see, in future may be add this parameter at spark/conf/hive-site.xml as well

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. What solved your issue ?

Comment: error logs says`16/04/07 07:15:02 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager`. Then I started reading my hive/conf/hive-site.xml. It had property hive.support.concurrency as true. But in spark/conf/hive-site.xml, I had no such property defined. So It required this to set on run time.