# Locking of hive tables while inserting using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert data into a hive table simultaneously from other tables within same database, the requirement is whenever a insert is happening, the other insert statement should wait till current one is completed.

This is working fine when loaded from Hive CLI, but with spark, the lock mechanism is not working.

I came to know that Spark doesn't support Lock in Hive table starting from version>2.0, **my spark version is 2.6**

[Will query from Spark hivecontext lock the hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701330/will-query-from-spark-hivecontext-lock-the-hive-table)

Is there any way that this can be done using spark?

Comment: have u not answered your own question?

Comment: parquet? what type of hive table?

Comment: It's an external table, and the data is a text file delimited by pipe(|). I'm searching for any other alternatives to achieve because this has to be done using spark.